# wpf change calendar day title foreground color

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I am trying to change calendar day title foreground color. I am using standard .net 4.0 Datepicker. The calendar is embedded in the Datepicker.

I have the following code in the resource file. but it does not work.

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="DayTitleTemplate">
                        <TextBlock
                                            FontWeight="Bold" 
                                            FontFamily="Verdana" 
                                            FontSize="9.5" 
                                            Foreground="Red" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            Text="{Binding}"
                                            Margin="0,6,0,6"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Can anyone help see what I am missing here?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx), it is about customizing the WPF Calendar controls and has this excerpt on the `DatePicker` Control.

From Link (*emphasis mine*):

> But all the styles and templates you can apply to the standalone Calendar control can also be applied to the Calendar control invoked from the dropdown in DatePicker. The **DatePicker control has a property named CalendarStyle of type Style, and the Style object you set to this property can contain setters for any property defined by Calendar, including the CalendarItemStyle, CalendarButtonStyle, and CalendarDayButtonStyle properties**.

See this link for the [`DatePicker` Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468215.aspx).

Comment: got it.  Thanks alot.       <Setter Property="CalendarStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DatePickerCalendarStyle}" />

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the foreground property is hard-coded in the default control template.  The way to change it is to copy-and-modify [the template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468218.aspx).

```
<Style x:Key="CalendarItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3,0,3" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Static CalendarItem.DayTitleTemplateResourceKey}">
                            <TextBlock 
                                <!-- Day header color here -->
                                Foreground="Red"
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                FontSize="9.5"
                                FontFamily="Verdana"
                                Margin="0,6,0,6"
                                Text="{Binding}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </DataTemplate>
```

You also might want to use `Foreground="{TemplateBinding}"`, so that way you can modify the color by setting the `Foreground` property on individual controls.

Comment: Thanks you both for the reply.

Comment: Thanks you both for the reply. I tried to copy the example template from MS site into a separate resource file and referenced it in the WPF form. But no matter what color I change it has no effect at all. I downloaded a sample code from code project which uses WPF-toolkit. I can see the sample working. The resource is defined very similar to what you have posted here as well as in MS site. However the sample is showing a calendar control, not DatePicker. Mine is a DatePicker that houses the calendar. It looks like the resource file is invisible by the "hidden" calendar. Any further ideas?

Comment: if I put the following into the resource file it will change the backgroud of the calendar.    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=CalendarBackgroundBrush, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Calendar}}" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0" x:Shared="false"
          GradientStops="{Binding GradientStops, Source={StaticResource MenuPopupBrush}}"                      
    />

Comment: @user1794925 I can't say why, I think this approach should work regardless of whether the control is nested somewhere.  All I can suggest is, try to get the template working on its own first, then work up to getting it working in the nested scenario.

Comment: Is there a day title foreground resource key? if yes what is it named? I googled it but could not find it. My application used a date picker and I am unlikely to be allowed to change it to a calendar. And with the nested calendar I can't make the template work. I am still trying....

Comment: OK. with the same resource file, the template works beautifully with calendar control. I can change it to whatever I like. But it just doesn't have any effect on nested calendar within datepicker:(

Comment: @user1794925 I doubt I can solve this, but can you post your updated code so that the question is up to date?